# CSV utf8 Import phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8

I am trying to import csv file with data in hebrew and arabic for my mysql database.

When i use the import tool from file, even i precise that the file is utf8 i have like that ????

I see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238124/csv-import-from-unicode-to-utf8-phpmyadmin) and i tried to make it :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv' INTO TABLE `table 1`
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

But unfortunately on the place to fill my field when it is english charachter it fill it and when it is hebrew or arabic charachter it fill with blank.

Ps: Before 6 years somebody post the same question but he says that it is a bug issue refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137175/using-load-data-infile-with-arabic-data)

Comment: Forgetting the engine part, check out the column level http://stackoverflow.com/q/2137175

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LOAD DATA INFILE with arabic data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137175/using-load-data-infile-with-arabic-data)

Comment: @Drew it is not duplicate before 6 years anyone has an answer!

Comment: Did you try that column level detail seen in the create table?

Comment: Are you using phpMyAdmin? If so, you should use the Import tab rather than typing in this SQL in to the query window manually.

Comment: Is your column collation `utf8`? Is the CSV file really *really* ***really*** encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: Possibly dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored